# Workings of web3.EthereumTesterProvider()?

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

Reading the web3.py [docs](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html), there are 3 providers, namely HTTPProvider, IPCProvider and WebsocketProvider.

Following the [quickstart guide](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html) on deploying contracts, what does the following line do:

`w3 = Web3(Web3.EthereumTesterProvider())`

I could not find much information on `Web3.EthereumTesterProvider()`, is it different from the 3 providers mentioned above? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can find info here
https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html

> EthereumTesterProvider 
> Warning
>
> Experimental: This provider is experimental. There are still
> significant gaps in functionality. However it is being actively
> developed and supported.
>
> classweb3.providers.eth_tester.EthereumTesterProvider(eth_tester=None)
> This provider integrates with the eth-tester library. The eth_tester constructor argument should be an instance of the EthereumTester or a subclass of BaseChainBackend class provided by the eth-tester library. If you would like a custom eth-tester instance to test with, see the eth-tester library documentation for details.

```
from web3 import Web3, EthereumTesterProvider
w3 = Web3(EthereumTesterProvider())
```